# Resizing Images in Linux

Tags: imagemagick

I have various folders with high res images sizes some more than 6000px x 4000px. some are 5000px x 3000px, size varies with folder to folder. I want to resize all images for saving resources like loading time/processing/memory space. I want to keep all images around minimum 3000x2000 max 3500x2200 . How I can do this with imagemagick in batch, Replacing original. Some one suggested my to use imagemagick with morgify on ubuntu?

Earlier when i had windows PC I used photosizer software. Selecting folder one by one, then process images with jpegMini software. So 5 mb photos decrease to the size to around 1.5 mb. Every folder contains images with different resolution. Its a long time consuming process.
For every folder i had to decrease % in fotosizer to keep image size around 3000*2000 more or less maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: `Some one suggested my to use imagemagick with morgify on ubuntu?` exactly what I wanted to say you while start my reading.  structure might be very easy test size then if needed convert size and loop to next image   that's all you need. something like `find . -type f -size +460 -exec convert {} -resize 75% {}.new \;` choosing size from a referenced image  and adapting options of convert to you own needs

Comment: what is +460?  I have lots of images, around 33k. 25 to 30 photos in each folder, folder cout is more that 1100. 90 gb. And Image size varies. Are you talking about some script? Which can automatically detect size of image and resize it to around 3500x2200.

Comment: was a file size example ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command below, either in a script, or just run from the command line, will resize all images in the current folder and any subfolder of the current folder.

```
find . -type f | grep -i -e '\.png$' -e '\.jpg$' -e '\.gif$` | xargs -I ___ mogrify -resize '3500x2200>' ___
```

If all the regular files in the folders below the current one are images, you can skip the grep step, and if not, you'll want to modify it to include all and only the extensions you have to deal with (–I assumed png, jpg and gif obviously). The `-i` makes it case insensitive.

Change the '3500x2200' as you see fit. It will keep aspect ratio and max out at those dimensions.

'3500x3500' might make more sense if some are landscape and some portrait and you don't want to discriminate against the portrait ones, and just want the larger dimension to be around 3500.

The '>' means it won't resize up just resize down.

You could also add something like `-quality 90%` after `mogrify` to reduce file size by lessening the quality.

`mogrify` overwrites the original files, as you requested, so be sure you really want to do this before pulling the trigger.

Comment: 3500x3500 is right, It works.

Comment: solution works - do not omit the ___ values.

Answer (score 0):

...a little late but perhaps it might help someone else:
On Ubuntu I use *converseen* (available in software). It's quite similar to Fotosizer (graphical interface) and does the job you are looking for.